# Why i can not convert an object to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, action

I have problem to undrestand this issue.

I have a generic Method that give an `Action<T>` to handle somthing. but i can not convert this object to T.

```
public interface T1 { }

public interface A : T1
{
    void A1();
}

public interface B : T1
{
    void A1();
}

public class Test : A, B
{
    void A.A1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    void B.A1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(  "B");

    }

    public void T100<T>(Action<T> call) where T : T1
    {
        call((T)this); // error comes from here
    }
}
```

whats wrong with this code?

Please tell me how can i create somthing like above.

Comment: Can you show us the error you get?

Comment: Constraint is `where T : T1`. So you may have another `interface C : T1` and so call T100 like `Test.T100(Action<C>......)`. This would be a valid call. But inside the method you would cast `this` to `C` and that's an invalid cast because none of them inherits from the other one. Why don't you cast to T1 instead? (`call((T1)this);`)

Comment: `// error comes from here` - _what_ error?

Comment: Also: this is asking for a fix to a (perceived) solution. But what is the problem?

Comment: @MatteoUmili That diagnosis is correct, but casting to `T1` shouldn't be necessary. The signature should be `public void T100(Action<T1> call)`, or even `public void T100(Action<Test> call)` if only `this` can be passed as the argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the compiler does not guarantee that the cast will be done correctly and safely.

You could use C# pattern matching :

```
public void T100<T>(Action<T> call) where T : T1
{
    if (this is T instance)
    {
        call(instance);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

*Usage* :

```
Test test = new Test();
test.T100<A>(firstIstance=> firstIstance.A1()); // This will output "A"
test.T100<B>(secondIstance => secondIstance.A1()); // This will output "B"
```

Comment: Whilst this addresses the compilation error, the proper solution is probably to use a non-generic method instead.